# Install rcplex on windows

Tags: r, cplex

I try to solve a very large optimization problem in R, so I want to install rcplex. I've not much experience with R, so excuse me if I ask stupid things.

First I installed cplex studio and rtools40. I've tried to follow the manual https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/INSTALL. Then I changed the `makevars.win` file to

```
ifeq "$(WIN)" "64"
               PKG_LIBS = -L"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/bin/x64_win64" -lcplex12100 -lm
               PKG_CPPFLAGS = -D_LP64 -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include"
          else
               PKG_LIBS = -L"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/bin/x86_win32" -lcplex12100 -lm
               PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include"
           endif
```

Then I used the command

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\Rgui.exe"  CMD build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual --md5 Rcplex_0.3-3
```

and get the errors:

```
warning unknown option --no-build-vignettes, warning unknown option --no-manual and warning unknown option --md5 .
```

If I tried to install it directly in R, I get the error

```r
Warning in install.packages(files[tarballs], .libPaths()[1L], repos = NULL, 
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library" is not writable
ERROR: dependency 'slam' is not available for package 'Rcplex'
```

So I don't know how to fix it.
EDIT
I changed the command to

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD  build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual --md5 C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz
```

and get the error

```
 ERROR
cannot change to directory 'C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz'
```

and for the command

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD  check  C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz
```

I get

```
* using log directory 'C:/Users/Jonas/Rcplex.Rcheck'
* using R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
* using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
* using session charset: ISO8859-1
* checking for file 'Rcplex/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* this is package 'Rcplex' version '0.3-3'
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for .dll and .exe files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking whether package 'Rcplex' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See 'C:/Users/Jonas/Rcplex.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
* DONE

Status: 1 ERROR
See
  'C:/Users/Jonas/Rcplex.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.
```

I don't know how to proceed. 
2.Edit
I changed it and get

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD  build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual --md5 C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Rcplex
* checking for file 'C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Rcplex/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'Rcplex':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
Warning in cleanup_pkg(pkgdir, Log)
  unable to run 'make clean' in 'src'
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* adding MD5 file
* building 'Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz'
Warning: file 'Rcplex/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
Warning: file 'Rcplex/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
```

I think the problem is now, that there is no  C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/bin/x86_win32 file. 
3.Edit
I've tried to install cplexAPI too, where I don't need these file and got the same error.

4.Edit I get then

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD INSTALL --build --no-multiarch .\Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz
* installing to library 'C:/Users/Jonas/Documents/R/win-library/4.0'
* installing *source* package 'Rcplex' ...
** package 'Rcplex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sum checked
** using staged installation
Warning in system("sh ./configure.win") 'sh' not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'Rcplex'
* removing 'C:/Users/Jonas/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcplex'
```

5.Edit 
Now I get

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD  build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual --md5 C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/cplexAPI
* checking for file 'C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/cplexAPI/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'cplexAPI':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking vignette meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* adding MD5 file
* building 'cplexAPI_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
```

and

```
C:\Users\Jonas>"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD INSTALL --build --no-multiarch .\Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz
* installing to library 'C:/Users/Jonas/Documents/R/win-library/4.0'
* installing *source* package 'Rcplex' ...
** package 'Rcplex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
"C:/rtools/mingw64/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -D_LP64 -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include"         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c Rcplex.c -o Rcplex.o
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1214:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1214:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1220:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1220:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1251:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1251:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1257:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1257:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1262:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1262:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1617:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1210/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1617:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:222: Rcplex.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcplex'
* removing 'C:/Users/Jonas/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcplex'
```

Also I get the same error,if I try to install cplexAPI

6.Edit
For cplexAPi I have the `makevars.win` file

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include"
PKG_LIBS=-L"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\bin\x64_win64" -lm -lcplex12100
```

and get

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD  build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual --md5 C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/cplexAPI
* checking for file 'C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/cplexAPI/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'cplexAPI':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking vignette meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* adding MD5 file
* building 'cplexAPI_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
```

and

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD INSTALL --build --no-multiarch .\cplexAPI_1.4.0.tar.gz
* installing to library 'C:/Users/Jonas/Documents/R/win-library/4.0'
* installing *source* package 'cplexAPI' ...
** package 'Rcplex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
"C:/rtools/mingw64/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include"         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c cplexAPI.c -o cplexAPI.o
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1214:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1214:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1220:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1220:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1251:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1251:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1257:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1257:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1262:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1262:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1617:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1617:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:222: cplexAPI.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cplexAPI'
* removing 'C:/Users/Jonas/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/cplexAPI'
```

So there is the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried to manually install package `slam`?

Comment: Also, `Rgui` isn't used for `CMD` stuff, just use `R.exe CMD build ...`.

Comment: Try `install.packages("slam")` in R first, and if it succeeds, try `.../R.exe CMD build ...` on the command-line (bash/cmd/whatever).

Comment: In a terminal (not within R), type in `R CMD build --help`, and it says `Usage: R CMD build [options] pkgdirs`, suggesting your build attempt should be on a *directory*, not on a tar-ball. `R CMD check` can be on directories or tarballs.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it. See 2. Edit.

Comment: It looks like the `R CMD build` worked with only warnings. Have you tried `installed.packages('Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz')` now?

Comment: I tried to install the package, but it didn't work. See 4.Edit.

Comment: In R, does `Sys.which("sh")` return something like `"c:\\Rtools40\\usr\\bin\\sh.exe"`?

Comment: Thank you, there was a problem with the path of rtools40. But the second warning for the build command is still a probem. See 5.Edit

Comment: You're going to need somebody more adept at troubleshooting C++. This package has not been updated in over four years, it wouldn't surprise me if there are compiler assumptions that are no longer true.

Comment: Thank you. But if I try to do the same with the recently updated package cplexAPI https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cplexAPI/index.html I get the same error.

Comment: Different authors, I suggest you reach out to them. (My "expertise" is tapped out, sorry.)

Comment: Thank you for all. I think I should proceed with cplexAPi, so I will start a new thread.